# Error la referenciar un objeto

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-11g, objeto

Estoy trabando de hacer unos ejercicios PL/SQL con objetos y me he atascado en el siguiente:

Crea un bloque anónimo en PL/SQL que realice lo siguiente: 
• Almacene en una instancia "listaCursos1" de dicha lista, con los dos cursos siguientes: 
El primer curso que debes almacenar en dicha lista debe tener los siguientes datos:

CODIGO: 11

NOMBRE: CURSO 11

REFPROFE: REFERENCIA AL PROFESOR CUYO CODIGO ES 12.

MAX_ALUMN: 25

FECHA_INIC: 1/02/2019

FECHA_FIN: 15/03/2019

NUM_HORAS: 50

El segundo curso que debes almacenar en dicha lista debe tener los siguientes datos:

CODIGO: 22

NOMBRE: CURSO 22

REFPROFE: REFERENCIA AL PROFESOR CUYO DNI ES 9111222G. MAX_ALUMN: 20

FECHA_INIC: 1/6/2019

FECHA_FIN: 30/6/2019

NUM_HORAS: 30

He llegado hasta este codigo:

DECLARE

LISTACURSOS1 LISTACURSOS := LISTACURSOS();

```
BEGIN

LISTACURSOS1.EXTEND;

LISTACURSOS1(1) := CURSOS(11, 'CURSO 11', REF(P) FROM PROFESORADO P WHERE P.CODIGO=12, 20, '01/02/2019', '15/3/2019', 50);
LISTACURSOS1(2) := CURSOS(22, 'CURSO 22', REF(P) FROM PROFESORADO P WHERE P.DNI=9111222G, '01/06/2019', '30/6/2019', 30);

END;
```

Pero parece que no tengo bien referenciado al profesor de la tabla profesorado, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
DECLARE

LISTACURSOS1 LISTACURSOS := LISTACURSOS();

BEGIN

LISTACURSOS1.EXTEND;

LISTACURSOS1(1) := CURSOS(11, 'CURSO 11', REF(P) FROM PROFESORADO P WHERE P.CODIGO=12, 20, '01/02/2019', '15/3/2019', 50);
LISTACURSOS1(2) := CURSOS(22, 'CURSO 22', REF(P) FROM PROFESORADO P WHERE P.DNI=9111222G, '01/06/2019', '30/6/2019', 30);



END;
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 50:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
ORA-06550: line 9, column 86:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + ; / at mod remainder rem return returning
   <an exponent (**)> and or || multiset
ORA-06550: line 9, column 122:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset me
ORA-06550: line 10, column 50:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multi
ORA-06550: line 10, column 88:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "G" when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + ; / at mod remainder rem return returning
   <an exponent (**)> and or || multiset
The symbol "return" was substituted for "G" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 10, column 120:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   , * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <an exponent (**)> as
   into || multiset bulk
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Este ejercicio es de 1º de DAM? Lo digo porque yo he hecho uno muy parecido.

Primero has tenido que crear el `array` no? Luego tienes que hacer los `select` para seleccionar los profesores a los que hace referencia, y yo añadí otro `extend` antes de meter los segundos datos.

Te paso mi código por si te sirve:

```
DECLARE     
listaCursos1 ListaCursos; 
P1 REF Profesor; 
P2 REF Profesor; 

BEGIN 
    listaCursos1:=ListaCursos();       
        SELECT REF(P) INTO P1 
    FROM Profesorado P WHERE P.codigo=3;    
        SELECT REF(P) INTO P2 
    FROM Profesorado P 
    WHERE P.dni='51083099F'; 

        listaCursos1.EXTEND; 
    listaCursos1(1):= Cursos(1, 'curso 1', P1, 20, '06/01/2011', '06/30/2011', 30); 

        listaCursos1.EXTEND; 
    listaCursos1(2):= Cursos(2, 'curso 2', P2, 20, '06/01/2011', '06/30/2011', 30); 

END;
```

Una cosa, a mí luego me pedía más ejercicios a raíz de este; si es así, acuérdate que tendrás que meter todo el código seguido, ya que los datos del `array` no se guardan de una sentencia a otra.

Comment: esto no soluciona directamente lo que necesita el OP.